# Refresh page automatically when MongoDB collection changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-handlebars

I'm making a Node.Js with MongoDB application and I need to refresh one of my HBS pages every time something changes on my MongoDB collection.

Don't know exactly what I should do. What is the best approach to do so?

Cheers.

Comment: You could look into `websockets`

Comment: you have to use websockets and mongodb change streams. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help. The best (and easiest) solution that I've found was using websockets with Socket.io.
I've used the following logic:

- On my new user page I've added this on my submit event:

```
socket.emit('UpdateOnDatabase');
```

- On my app.js:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('UpdateOnDatabase', function(msg){
        socket.broadcast.emit('RefreshPage');
    });
});
```

- And in my Home page, wich is the one that I want to refresh:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('RefreshPage', function (data) {
        location.reload();
    });
```

I've changed my way of thinking a bit but it's working exactly as I want.

Cheers.

Comment: Hey I  needed this solution aswell but could you please clarify on how you are using that socket.emit('UpdateOnDatabase'); because I cant get it to work for myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can read into Mongodb or mongoose change streams  which you can watch on change

Typical example from the mongoose website:

```js
// Create a new mongoose model
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema, 'Person');

// Create a change stream. The 'change' event gets emitted when there's a
// change in the database
Person.watch().
  on('change', data => console.log(new Date(), data));

// Insert a doc, will trigger the change stream handler above
console.log(new Date(), 'Inserting doc');
await Person.create({ name: 'Axl Rose' });
```

you can read more on the [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) or [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) website